# Android start an activity from a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-pendingintent

I have an application that allows video calls. 
It works using firebase notification. The flow is

1) push comes
2) PushService starts my CallService.
3) CallService starts IncomingCallActivityby PendingIntent .

pushService -> callService -> callActivity

This approach works if the app is on the foreground or if the app was minimized. But if the app wasn't started at all or closed by the user, the call chain doesn't work. The callActivity doesn't start. Is there any way to start the activity?

```
val intent = CallActivity.newIntent(this, someExtra)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

 PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                123,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
            ).send()
```

Comment: I have a similar app. What I do is upon receipt of the firebase push I start the service. The service then issues a notification and plays a ring sound. If the user clicks on the notification it brings my app to the front. Would this paradigm work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app targets API level 29 or higher, you cannot launch an `Activity` from a `Service` if the `Service` is in the background and the app has not got any existing activities (which is the case when the app is not running, as you've seen). This restriction was added in API level 29 to reduce UI interference from background apps. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts for an explanation of the exact conditions that are necessary to allow a background `Service` to launch an `Activity`.

To verify that this is your problem, change your targetSDK to 28 or lower and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yep. It works on API level less than 29 exclude Xiaomi devices. I have tested on 28 API Xiaomi and it hasn't worked like on 29 API. I figured out it is because of MIUI. Looks like I have a lot of work to do now. Thanks for the link.